# AUCTeX folding and square brackets in math mode

Tags: math-mode, auctex, brackets, code-folding

I want to use the folding functionality of AUCTeX, mainly to replace math macros with the corresponding symbols. But at the same time I want to continue to use square or curly brackets additionally to parentheses. But AUCTeX hides then square or curly brackets and their content.

So if I write:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$a \to [b \to c]$

\end{document}
```

and then apply `TeX-fold-buffer` I get as result:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$a →$

\end{document}
```

What I would like to get is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$a  → [b → c]$

\end{document}
```

How can I prevent AUCTeX folding from hiding square or curly brackets and their content in math mode?

Comment: Actually `$a [b \to c]$` is folded as expected to `$a [b → c]$`, so it isn't a problem with square brackets but perhaps a conflict between the `\to` and the brackets.

Comment: @giordano: It seems to be a conflict between _any_ folded math macro and square and curly brackets. For every math macro in LaTeX-fold-math-spec-list I tested the problem appears.

Comment: You're right.  I found the problem: folding relies on `TeX-find-macro-end-helper` to detect the end of the macro to be folded, but this considers square brackets and curly braces as part of the macro, so they will be always folded when they follow a math macro.  I need to think about a solution (probably a redefinition of `TeX-find-macro-end-helper`).  Thank you for having spotted this issue!